# AS3 | How to use var for name?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

My code is:

```
for (var i:int=1; i <= 12; i++) {
    MovieClip(getChildByName('mouse' + '_' + i)).addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, chooseTool);
}

function chooseTool(e:MouseEvent):void {
    Mouse.hide();

    var cursor:MovieClip = new "here is e.target.name"();
    addChild(cursor);

    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, follow);
}

function follow(e:MouseEvent):void {
    cursor.x=mouseX;
    cursor.y=mouseY;
}
```

How to use "e.target.name" for name ?
Should become something like:
1) Click on button with name mouse_4
2) Function chooseTool create new MovieClip with name mouse_4();
example: `var cursor:MovieClip = new mouse_4();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using `getDefinitionByName` ([Adobe documentation: getDefinitionByName](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#getDefinitionByName%28%29))

```
for (var i:int=1; i <= 12; i++) {
    MovieClip(getChildByName('mouse' + '_' + i)).addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, chooseTool);
}

function chooseTool(e:MouseEvent):void {
    Mouse.hide();

    var o:Object = getDefinitionByName(e.target.name);
        // ^ Gets a reference to the class object based on a string

    if(o == null) throw new Error("Unable to find class " + e.target.name);

    var c:Class = o as Class;
    var cursor:MovieClip = new c() as MovieClip;
    addChild(cursor);

    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, follow);
}

function follow(e:MouseEvent):void {
    cursor.x=mouseX;
    cursor.y=mouseY;
}
```

But this feels very ill structured way of doing it. Instead I would use a factory method ([Factory pattern on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern))

```
for (var i:int=1; i <= 12; i++) {
    MovieClip(getChildByName('mouse' + '_' + i)).addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, chooseTool);
}

function chooseTool(e:MouseEvent):void {
    Mouse.hide();

    var cursor:MovieClip = getCursor(e.target);
    addChild(cursor);

    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, follow);
}

function follow(e:MouseEvent):void {
    cursor.x=mouseX;
    cursor.y=mouseY;
}

function getCursor(target:MovieClip):MovieClip
{
    switch(target.name)
    {
        case "cursor_4":
            return new cursor_4();

        default:
            return new default_mouse();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it like that.  That is not realy a name would be a new class/type. The solution is to extend the MovieClip and pass that name as a parameter . I do not know what you want to achieve but this is a good way to start.

```
class MyClip extends MovieClip 
{
    public var name:String="";
    public function MyClip(name:String) 
    {
        super();
    this.name=name;
    }
} 
}
```

The code will look something like that and you can add all the logic related with  this type inside this class.

Answer (score 1):

You can't Instantiate like this new "e.target.name"();
But if you want to take the reference of target,you can try this.

var cursor:MovieClip =e.target as MovieClip;

you cannot modify the name property of cursor.